# How to separate date and time in DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I am a beginner of Python.
I have the dataframe `df_all_data_0` with column `time_in`:

```
2018-01-13 13:17:29
2018-01-06 17:49:43
2018-01-18 09:44:37
2018-01-04 10:45:52
2018-01-11 12:58:31
```

I want to separate the date (e.g., 2018-01-13) and time (13:17:29).
What I tried:

```
pd.to_datetime(df_all_data_0['time_in']).
date_str = df_all_data_0.strptime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

But I have en error:

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-d662eee68034> in <module>()
      8 
      9 
---> 10 date_str = df_all_data_0.strptime('%Y-%m-%d')
     11 #print(type(date_str)) # <class 'str'>
     12 #print(date_str) # 2017-10-24

/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   2968             if name in self._info_axis:
   2969                 return self[name]
-> 2970             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   2971 
   2972     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'strptime'
```

How do it correct?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `pd.Series.dt.normalize` to extract date with time set to 0 and `pd.Series.dt.time` to extract time:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

mystr = StringIO("""2018-01-13 13:17:29
2018-01-06 17:49:43
2018-01-18 09:44:37
2018-01-04 10:45:52
2018-01-11 12:58:31""")

df = pd.read_csv(mystr, sep='|', header=None, names=['DateTime'])

df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
df['Date'], df['Time'] = df['DateTime'].dt.normalize(), df['DateTime'].dt.time

print(df)

#              DateTime       Date      Time
# 0 2018-01-13 13:17:29 2018-01-13  13:17:29
# 1 2018-01-06 17:49:43 2018-01-06  17:49:43
# 2 2018-01-18 09:44:37 2018-01-18  09:44:37
# 3 2018-01-04 10:45:52 2018-01-04  10:45:52
# 4 2018-01-11 12:58:31 2018-01-11  12:58:31
```

Note the `Time` column will have `dtype` object:

```
print(df.dtypes)

# DateTime    datetime64[ns]
# Date        datetime64[ns]
# Time                object
# dtype: object
```